# Hi, I am using a function in R shiny to format numbers with a method but that returns 0 to 0.0K while required is - or NA

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I don't know how to write JS queries and i found this answer on stack overflow
`formatThousands <- JS(   "function(data) {",   "return (data / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'K'",   "}")`
this function returns 0 to 0.0K but I want to display 0 as '-' or 'NA' in my R shiny data table. I don't want to convert these numbers into a string because that will disable my sorting functionality in that. Can anyone help me with this how-to modify or adding that component as well?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please don't say 'hi' on Stack Overflow. And minimize the title :-) Also you should provide a reproducible example, so that we know exactly what you are doing. I had to guess in order to answer.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent for the feedback and will provide a reproducible example next time and you guessed it perfectly right, it solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using this function in a `render` option. If you want to preserve the sorting, you have to use the `type` argument. Regarding your question, you can simply return a value conditional to `data == 0`:

```
JS(
  "function(data, type, row){",
  "  if(type === 'display'){",
  "    return data == 0 ? '-' : ((data / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'K');",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)
```

Comment: Hi, Stephane the solution provided worked well but I got stuck if we had data as NA in R and still want to replace it with `-` what should be the condition, I tried NA and that didn't work. Can you please help me with this one as well?

Comment: @SumitKumar Probably `NA` is converted to `null` in JavaScript or something like that. `null` and `0` are "falsy" in JavaScript, so you can probably do `return data ? (data / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'K' : '-';`.

Comment: Stephane thanks for the quick response, but what this does is returns every number as dash rather than converting non-null numbers to K

Comment: @SumitKumar I've just tried and this works. Double-check your code.